# how to add event listener in forms without class Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Hi i tried to have to comboBox in symfony the modeles depend the marques but i can't add the event listener `

```
 public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {


        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();




        $marques = $em->getRepository('EcommerceBundle:Marque')->findAll();
        $tableau = array();

        foreach($marques as $marq)
        {
            array_push($tableau, $marq->getId());

        }

        $em1 = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();




        $modeles = $em->getRepository('EcommerceBundle:Modeles')->findAll();
        $tableau1 = array();

        foreach( $modeles as $model)
        {
            array_push($modeles, $model->getId());

        }

            $form=$this->createFormBuilder()
     ->add('marques', ChoiceType::class, array(
         'choices'  => $tableau,
         'choice_label' => function ($key) {
             $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('EcommerceBundle:Marque');
             $marques = $em->findOneById($key);

             return $marques->getNom();
         },
         'attr'=>array('class' =>'id_of_the_form_field','value'=>'5')
     ))
      ->add('Modeles', ChoiceType::class, array(


                   'attr'=>array('class' =>'modeles','value'=>'5')
                ))

       ->add('Chercher', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Valider'))
     ->getForm();

        $marque = function(FormInterface $form, $marques) {
            $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Modeles::class);

            $modele = $repository->findByMarque($marques);

if($modele) {
    $mode = array();
    foreach ($modele as $mod) {
        $mod[$mod->getNom()] = $mod->getNom();
    }
}else{
    $mode=null;

}

            $form->add('modele','choice', array('attr' => array('class'   => 'modeles'),
                'choices' => $mode));
        };

        $form->get('marques')->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) use ($marques) {
            $marques($event->getForm()->getParent(),$event->getForm()->getData());
        });


        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            var_dump($form->getData());
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('presentzation', array('id' => $marque)));

            }


        return $this->render('EcommerceBundle:Marques:tousMarques.html.twig', array(
            'marques' => $marques,'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
```

`I have error in`Attempted to call an undefined method named "addEventListener" of class "Symfony\Component\Form\Form".
`

Comment: `addEventListener` should be called on `FormBuilder`, not the form.